# CSS3 cross browser issue

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to make a div flip onclick of a button using transform: rotatex, and preserve-3d. It is working fine on Chrome but no luck with FF and IE(support only version 11 and above). I would appreciate any help.

**HTML**

```
     <div class="flip col-sm-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="face front">
                <div class="small-video">
                    <div class="clip-view clip-view-tenth">
                        <t:tv.newvideo media="media" width="250" height="145" includeJs="false" fluid="true" watched="watched" showtitle="false" showdescription="true" />
                        <div class="mask" onClick="$(this).hide(); $(this).parents('.clip-view').find('.video-js').trigger('play'); return false;">
                            <div class="tool-icon tooltip-icon-small">
                                <t:icon icon="play" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <t:delegate to="block:titleBlock" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="face back">
                <t:delegate to="block:clipChapters" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    width: 400px;
    height:290px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;}
.flip .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotatex(-180deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    transform: rotatex(-180deg);

}
.flip .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;    
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.flip .card .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}

.flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.flip .card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some styles you wrote only for -webkit- browsers, might that be the problem ?

Also see here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d 3d transforms ( preserve-3d ) are not supported in IE.

So add also the styles for Firefox not only the Webkit ones:

```
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    width: 400px;
    height:290px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotatex(-180deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;    
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:0.5s; 
    transition:0.5s; 
}

.flip .card .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}

.flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.flip .card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    transform:rotateX(-180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateX(-180deg);
}
```

Comment: I have added cross browser filter with no luck. Had to redesign because  preserve-3d is not fully supported yet by IE.

Comment: yep. that's what i wrote in my answer :) . cross browser was for moz only fix